# How to get SVG to stretch to table cell vertically?

Tags: html, css, svg

I have a simple table with SVG in its table cell:

```html
<html>
<body>
<table style="width: 8em;">
<tr>
<td style="border: 1px solid black;">
<svg viewBox="0 0 1 1" style="width: 1.37em;" preserveAspectRatio="none">
<polyline points="0,0 1,0.5 0,1" style="fill: blue;"></polyline>
</svg>
</td>
<td style="border: 1px solid black;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, other cells in the row can be too long, and hence cause the row height to change from the default, introducing gaps between the SVG and its bounding upper and lower borders.

How can I get the SVG to automatically stretch or shrink to fill its cell vertically, without changing its horizontal size?

Answer (score 2):

One solution would be to make it a background image. You can either put the SVG code into a separate file, or you can [percent-encode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_encoding) it to use in a data URI.

```html
<table style="width: 8em;">
<tr>
<td style="border: 1px solid black; width: 1.37em; background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns=%22http://www.w3.org/2000/svg%22 viewBox=%220 0 1 1%22 preserveAspectRatio=%22none%22%3E%3Cpolyline points=%220,0 1,0.5 0,1%22 style=%22fill: blue;%22%3E%3C/polyline%3E%3C/svg%3E');"></td>
<td style="border: 1px solid black;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Ouch, this is an order of magnitude uglier than I expected. Thanks though, I'll see how it compares to the other solution.

Answer (score 1):

Other solution is this, position relative to the td so that the svg is contained inside it, because the svg is now position absolute so that it accepts height 100%, but position abosulte makes the element don't ocupy space that why it's needed to add width to the td

```html
   <html>
  <body>
<table style="width: 8em">
  <tr>
    <td style="border: 1px solid black; position: relative; width: 1.37em">
      <svg
        viewBox="0 0 1 1"
        style="width: 1.37em; height: 100%; position: absolute; top: 0"
        preserveAspectRatio="none"
      >
        <polyline points="0,0 1,0.5 0,1" style="fill: blue"></polyline>
      </svg>
    </td>
    <td style="border: 1px solid black">Lorem ipsum dolor ipsum dolor ipsum dolor ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
  </tr>
</table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Now to allow text in the same td one approach is to use a little javascript to calculate the height. I did some research and it seems that making an element fit parent height comes down to [3 options](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-force-child-div-to-be-100-of-parent-divs-height-without-specifying-parents-height/), position absolute (previous code snippet), display flex and display grid, posititon absolute will not allow text in the same td, display flex and grid would remove the the display table-cell of the td which will mess with the table. So with some js it loos like this:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      table td {
        border: 1px solid black;
      }

      .svg-container {
        display: flex;
      }

      .svg-container svg {
        width: 1.37em;
        align-self: stretch;
      }

      .svg-container svg polyline {
        fill: blue;
      }

      .svg-container span {
        align-self: center;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <table style="width: 8em">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="svg-container">
            <svg viewBox="0 0 1 1" preserveAspectRatio="none">
              <polyline points="0,0 1,0.5 0,1"></polyline>
            </svg>
            <span>One</span>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor ipsum dolor ipsum dolor ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="svg-container">
            <svg viewBox="0 0 1 1" preserveAspectRatio="none">
              <polyline points="0,0 1,0.5 0,1"></polyline>
            </svg>
            <span>Two Here</span>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>

  <script>
    [...document.querySelectorAll(".svg-container")].forEach((container) => {
      const parentHeight = container.parentNode.getBoundingClientRect().height;
      container.style.height = `${parentHeight}px`;
    });
  </script>
</html>
```

If javascript is not an option then I can only think of a "pseudo table" made with divs, but you will have to control the width of the columns manually:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
      .pseudo-table {
        width: 200px;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
      }

      .pseudo-table .row,
      .pseudo-table .column {
        display: flex;
      }

      .pseudo-table .column {
        border: 1px solid black;
      }

      .after-svg {
        align-self: center;
      }

      .col1 {
        min-width: 65px;
      }

      .col2,
      .col3 {
        min-width: 100px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="pseudo-table">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="column col1">
          <svg viewBox="0 0 1 1" style="width: 1.37em" preserveAspectRatio="none">
            <polyline points="0,0 1,0.5 0,1" style="fill: blue"></polyline>
          </svg>
          <span class="after-svg">One</span>
        </div>
        <div class="column col2">Lorem ipsum dolor meca vade Lorem ipsum dolor meca vade</div>
        <div class="column col3">Other colum</div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="column col1">
          <svg viewBox="0 0 1 1" style="width: 1.37em" preserveAspectRatio="none">
            <polyline points="0,0 1,0.5 0,1" style="fill: blue"></polyline>
          </svg>
          <span class="after-svg">Two here</span>
        </div>
        <div class="column col2">Lorem ipsum</div>
        <div class="column col3">Other colum with more</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Couldn’t you just style the `<td>` itself with `width: 1.37em` rather than having a spacer `<div>`?

Comment: +1 thanks, but now I'm running into another issue - I can't add any text right after the SVG (in the same td). Do you know of any way to avoid dedicating an entire cell to the SVG?

Comment: Edited the answer with a few options 

Comment: Ah wow, this is way less straightforward than I hoped. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can insert the SVG into the background. Here, I use a data URI of the following SVG document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1 1" preserveAspectRatio="none">
  <polyline points="0,0 1,0.5 0,1" style="fill: blue;"/>
</svg>
```

```css
svg {
  display: block;
}

.arrow {
  width: 2em;
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0idXRmLTgiPz4KPHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCAxIDEiIHByZXNlcnZlQXNwZWN0UmF0aW89Im5vbmUiPgogIDxwb2x5bGluZSBwb2ludHM9IjAsMCAxLDAuNSAwLDEiIHN0eWxlPSJmaWxsOiBibHVlOyIvPgo8L3N2Zz4=');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<table style="width: 8em;">
  <tr>
    <td class="arrow" style="border: 1px solid black;">
    </td>
    <td style="border: 1px solid black;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I don't know how important the table is, but this can be applied to any element, like here, a paragraph:

```css
svg {
  display: block;
}

p {
  width: 6em;
  padding-left: 2em;
  position: relative;
}

p:before {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -2em;
  content: "";
  width: 2em;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0idXRmLTgiPz4KPHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCAxIDEiIHByZXNlcnZlQXNwZWN0UmF0aW89Im5vbmUiPgogIDxwb2x5bGluZSBwb2ludHM9IjAsMCAxLDAuNSAwLDEiIHN0eWxlPSJmaWxsOiBibHVlOyIvPgo8L3N2Zz4=');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
```